# How do I load a web page in a laravel blade template div with Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to load and show facebook in small box of a laravel blade template. I am using this javascript but facebook is not loading ?

Here what I am using :

```
<div id="fblogin"></div>

<script>
 function load_home (e) {
  (e || window.event).preventDefault();

  fetch("https://facebook.com")
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((html) => {
    document.getElementById("fblogin").innerHTML = html;
   })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.warn(error);
   });
   }
 </script>
```

I have also tried iframe but not loading the page.
Please help.
Here is the box where I want to show the facebook page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need not only declare function but call it as well

```
load_home();
```

Second, you do not need preventDefault at all, this line is not needed

```
  (e || window.event).preventDefault();
```

And third, FB lets you access their server from their domain only. This is a CORS policy. You cannot connect to their server from other websites.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the `load_home()` function. If you call you will see `preventDefault` error then remove `(e || window.event).preventDefault();` this line. Then you will have this error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://facebook.com/' from origin 'some origine' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  Facebook blocked this request.

```
Fetch
Jquery Load
Ajax get
```

All uses XMLHttpRequest  Technnology. You can not load fb with this.